# listado de productos, con publicidad intercalada

Tags: html, angular, ionic

tengo un listado de productos que voy mostrando en la app con su imagen, precio, etc que recojo de la base de datos, estos se van mostrando en un div que se van repitiendo dos horizontal y ahora necesito intercalar publicidad dentro de estos div es decir que por ejemplo cada 5 productos el 6 sea publicidad, pero no se como modificar este array para que suceda eso pondre el codigo para mostrar ahora cómo está funcionando.

Bueno estoy trabajando con ionic este es el código :

```js
import { Component, OnInit,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';
import { Router ,NavigationExtras} from '@angular/router';
import { UtilService } from '../utils/util.service';
import {FilterPage} from '../modals/filter/filter.page';
import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { orderBy, uniqBy } from 'lodash';

@Component({
  selector: 'home-page',
  templateUrl: './home.page.html',
  styleUrls: [
    './home.page.scss'
  ]
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
  
  dummy = Array(20);
  product_list=[];
  search="";
  dummy_product_list=[];
  
  filterdata={
    'filter_category':'',
    'filter_minprice':'',
    'filter_maxprice':'',
    'filter_location':''
  };

  current_index=0;
  segment_size=6;

  constructor(public api: ApiService ,   public router: Router,    public util: UtilService,    public modalController: ModalController ) { 


  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }
 
  ionViewWillEnter() {
    
    this.get_all_product();
  }

  onSearchChange() {
    console.log(this.search);
    this.product_list = this.dummy_product_list.filter((item: any) => {
      return item.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase());
    });  
  }

  get_all_product(){
    this.current_index=0;
    this.segment_size=6;
      var data = {
        'user_id': this.api.userdata.user_id,
        'api_token': this.api.userdata.api_token
      };
    this.dummy = Array(20);

    this.api.get_all_product(data).subscribe((res) => {
        this.dummy = [];
        if (res.status == '1') {
          var tmp_result = [];

          for (let i=0;i<res.data.length;i++){
            let distance = this.distanceInKmBetweenEarthCoordinates(this.api.userdata.lat, this.api.userdata.lng, res.data[i].lat, res.data[i].lng);
            console.log('distance', distance);
            res.data[i].distance=distance
            tmp_result.push(res.data[i]);       
            
          }
           
          tmp_result = orderBy(tmp_result, 'distance', 'asc');

          this.dummy_product_list=tmp_result; 
          this.product_list=tmp_result;
          console.log(this.dummy_product_list);
          this.refresh_filter();
        }else{
          this.dummy_product_list=[];
          this.product_list=[];
        }
    }, error => {
      
      this.dummy = [];
      this.util.errorToast("Error en el servidor.");
    });
  }

  loadData(event) {
    var self=this;
    // setTimeout(() => {
    //   console.log('load more');
    //   self.current_index=self.current_index+self.segment_size;
    //    console.log(self.current_index);
    //   // console.log(this.dummy_message_list);

    //   var segment_array=self.dummy_product_list.slice(self.current_index,self.current_index+self.segment_size);
    //   // console.log(segment_array);

    //   self.product_list=self.product_list.concat(segment_array);
    //   // console.log(self.message_list);

    //   event.target.complete();

    //   // App logic to determine if all data is loaded
    //   // and disable the infinite scroll
    //   if (this.product_list.length >= this.dummy_product_list.length) {
    //     event.target.disabled = true;
    //   }
    // }, 500);
  }



  distanceInKmBetweenEarthCoordinates(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
    console.log(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2);
    const earthRadiusKm = 6371;

    const dLat = this.degreesToRadians(lat2 - lat1);
    const dLon = this.degreesToRadians(lon2 - lon1);

    lat1 = this.degreesToRadians(lat1);
    lat2 = this.degreesToRadians(lat2);

    const a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
      Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2);
    const c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    return earthRadiusKm * c;
  }

  degreesToRadians(degrees) {
    return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
  }

  open_product(item){
    const navData: NavigationExtras = {
      queryParams: {
        product_details:JSON.stringify(item)
      }
    };
    this.router.navigate(['app/home/product_details'],navData);
  }

  open_chat(chat_item){ 

    var data = {
      'user_id': this.api.userdata.user_id,
      'api_token': this.api.userdata.api_token,
      'type':'product',
      'product_id':chat_item.product_id,
      'auction_id':0,
      'seller_user_id':chat_item.user_id,
      'bid_user_id':this.api.userdata.user_id
    };

    this.util.show();

    this.api.open_chatroom(data).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      this.util.hide();
      if (res.status == '1') {        
        const navData: NavigationExtras = {
          queryParams: {
            chat_item:JSON.stringify(res.data)
          }
        };
        this.router.navigate(['chat'],navData);
      }else{
        this.util.errorToast("Can't open chat.Try again!");        
      }
    }, error => {
      this.util.hide();
      this.util.errorToast("Error en el servidor.");
    });


   }


   async open_filter(){
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: FilterPage,    
      backdropDismiss: false,
      componentProps: {
        'filterdata': this.filterdata
      }
    });

    modal.onDidDismiss().then((dataReturned) => {
      if (dataReturned && dataReturned.data) {
         this.filterdata = dataReturned.data;
         console.log(this.filterdata);
         this.show_filteresult();
      }else{
        console.log("No Filter");        
      }
    });
      await modal.present().then(() => {
    });
   }

   show_filteresult(){
     var tmp_list=this.product_list;
     var self=this;

     if (this.filterdata.filter_category!=''){
      tmp_list= tmp_list.filter((item: any) => {
        return item.category_title.toLowerCase().includes(self.filterdata.filter_category.toLowerCase()) ;
      });  
     }

     if (this.filterdata.filter_location!=''){
      tmp_list= tmp_list.filter((item: any) => {
        return item.address.city.toLowerCase().includes(self.filterdata.filter_location.toLowerCase()) ;
      });  
     }

     if (this.filterdata.filter_minprice!='' || this.filterdata.filter_maxprice!=''){
      tmp_list= tmp_list.filter((item: any) => {
        return item.price>=this.filterdata.filter_minprice && this.filterdata.filter_maxprice>=item.price ;
      });  
     }

     this.product_list=tmp_list;

   }
      
   refresh_filter(){
     console.log(this.filterdata);
    this.onSearchChange();
    this.show_filteresult();
   }


}
```

```html
<ion-header class="ion-no-border">

  <div class="div_searchbar">
    <ion-searchbar animated="true" mode="ios" [(ngModel)]="search"    placeholder="Buscar en scooby " [debounce]="250" class="search_bar" (ionChange)="onSearchChange()"></ion-searchbar>    
    <ion-button  fill="clear"  (click)="open_filter()">
      <ion-icon slot="icon-only" mode="md"  name="options-outline"  ></ion-icon>
    </ion-button>
  </div>

  <div class="filter_div" *ngIf="filterdata.filter_category!='' || filterdata.filter_location!='' ||  filterdata.filter_minprice!='' || filterdata.filter_maxprice!='' ">
    <div class="filter_item"  *ngIf="filterdata.filter_category!=''" >
      <span class="filter_label"> Categoria:</span><span style="margin:auto">{{filterdata.filter_category }}</span>
      <ion-icon name="close-circle-outline" class="filterclose_btn" (click)="filterdata.filter_category='';refresh_filter()"></ion-icon>
    </div>
    <div class="filter_item" *ngIf="filterdata.filter_location!=''" (click)="filterdata.filter_location='';refresh_filter()">
      <span class="filter_label"> Ubicacion:</span> <span style="margin:auto">{{ filterdata.filter_location}}</span>
      <ion-icon name="close-circle-outline" class="filterclose_btn"></ion-icon>
    </div>
    <div class="filter_item" *ngIf="filterdata.filter_minprice!='' || filterdata.filter_maxprice!=''" (click)="filterdata.filter_minprice='';filterdata.filter_maxprice='';refresh_filter();"> 
      <span class="filter_label"> Precio:</span> <span style="margin:auto">{{filterdata.filter_minprice +'€'+ '  ~  ' + filterdata.filter_maxprice +'€'}}</span>
      <ion-icon name="close-circle-outline" class="filterclose_btn"></ion-icon>
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="content">
  <div class="main_content_div"  *ngIf="dummy?.length>0">    
    <ion-row class="items-row">
      <ion-col size="6" class="product_col" *ngFor="let product_item of dummy;let i = index">
        <div class="product_item">
          <ion-skeleton-text animated style="   width: 90%;  margin: auto; height: 25vw; "></ion-skeleton-text>

          <div class="product_infodiv">
            <div class="product_rowdiv"  >
              <ion-skeleton-text animated style=" width: 90%;height: 10px;margin: auto;  "> </ion-skeleton-text>
            </div>
            <div class="product_rowdiv">
              <ion-skeleton-text animated style=" width: 90%; height: 10px;margin: auto;  "> </ion-skeleton-text>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>       
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
 </div>

  <div class="main_content_div" *ngIf="dummy?.length==0">    
    <p class="title_p"> Productos cerca de ti </p>
    <ion-row class="items-row">
      <ion-col size="6" class="product_col" *ngFor="let product_item of product_list;let i = index">
        <div class="product_item">
          <ion-img class="product_image" [src]="product_item.image_list[0].file_url" (click)="open_product(product_item)" ></ion-img>

          <div class="product_infodiv">
            <div class="product_rowdiv"  (click)="open_product(product_item)" >
               <p class="product_price"> {{product_item.price +'€' }} </p>
               <ion-icon src="assets/icon/pin.svg" class="pin_icon"></ion-icon>
               <p class="product_city"> {{product_item.address.city }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="product_rowdiv">
              <p class="product_title" >  {{product_item.title }}</p>
              <ion-icon *ngIf="product_item.user_id!=api.userdata.user_id" slot="icon-only" src="assets/icon/chat_btn.svg" class="chat_icon" (click)="open_chat(product_item)"></ion-icon>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>       
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>

  </div>

 
 <div class="main_content_div" *ngIf="dummy?.length==0 && product_list?.length==0">    
  <p class="hint_p"> ¡No hay datos! </p>
</div>

</ion-content>
```

Bueno eso es el codigo que tengo en la página home.ts y home.html el problema está en la modificación del array que no se como hacer para intercalar la publicidad si pudiera encontrar un tutorial que alguien sepa lo agradeceria ya que de cero solo no se como hacerlo, gracias de antemano espero una respuesta lo agradeceria o si hace falta invito a un café en fin hay momentos que una se desespera.

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre una solución bastante sencilla. En tu ngfor tienes acceso a la variable i (que es el índice). Podrías crear un array con la publicidad que quieres mostrar, y dentro del contenido del ngfor pon un div con la publicidad y este div tendría un ngif, y compara, si el i es múltiplo de 5 (osea, cada 5 elementos dará true) y así insertas publicidad cada X productos sin alterar tu array de productos.

Si no, pues tendrías que modificar el array utilizando un map, siguiendo básicamente la misma lógica, y quue cada 5 elementos (o una cantidad X) haces una inserción de un nuevo elemento con la publicidad que necesitas.

Espero te sirva la sugerencia.

Comment: Hola kevin, gracias por el aporte lo intentare a ver si me salgo, no se mucho pero se agradece.